# How to undeploy an asp.net 2.0 website

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, web-deployment, asp.net-2.0, undeploy

I have a deployed version of an asp.net 2.0 website developed by visual studio 2005... But unfortunately, the source code has been deleted...

I want to get the source code version of the website from the deployed version

There are tools to extract code from DLL to class libraries but I tried to search a lot I don't find any tools to extract DLL to asp.net code-behind

What can I do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: To avoid such things happening in the future I would recommend you using source control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you could try to de-compile but its not very easy to understand or put the code into any further "easy" development once its de-compiled.But it would of course give you a head start , and if your website was published with enough debug info it probably might give you something real close to the original.

Give this a try :

[Red Gate Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/)